# Обратная совместимость Django 1.5 к Django 1.4

Tags: django

Есть несколько проектов на Django 1.4, с которыми работаю на Windows 7. Django установлен глобально, не под виртуальным окружением. Могу ли я со спокойной душой удалить версию 1.4 и накатить версию 1.5? Проекты совсем несложные, использовал возможности фреймворка по минимуму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете, если 1.4 не ругалась на использование deprecated фич. Если ругалась - возможно, эти фичи в 1.5 убраны совсем.

Есть еще официальный список [backwards incompatible changes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-5), но там ничего критичного нет обычно.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю ничего страшного не случится. Не помню насчет deprecated, вроде не встречалось